# Create a generic type that pulls return values from methods

Tags: typescript

Here I have a class `Methods` with some simple ones.

```
class Methods {
    name = (): string => "bob"
    age = (): number => 42
    asyncAge = async (): Promise<number> => 42
}
```

I have a type that gets all the values from the methods and creates a union.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type MethodReturns<C, M extends Array<keyof C>> = UnionToIntersection<{
    [K in M[number]]: C[K] extends ((...args: any[]) => any) ? ReturnType<C[K]> : never
}[M[number]]>

type x = MethodReturns<Methods, ['name', 'asyncAge']>
// type x = string & Promise<number>
```

However, this is what my desired outcome would be. I need the return types to also contain the method name as a property.

```
// type x = { name: string } & { asyncAge: number }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type ThenArg<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T

type MethodReturns<C, M extends Array<keyof C>> = {
    [K in M[number]]: C[K] extends ((...args: any[]) => any) ? ThenArg<ReturnType<C[K]>> : never
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you would prefer to not have to pass that array as the 2nd generic type argument, but if so then you can do this:

```
type UnwrapPromise<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T;

type MethodReturns<Obj extends {}> = {
    [K in keyof Obj]: Obj[K] extends ((...args: any[]) => any)
        ? UnwrapPromise<ReturnType<Obj[K]>>
        : never;
};
```